# SQL Server conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '-49.15' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, type-conversion, sql-server-2014

I received this error:

> SQL Server Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '-49.15' to data type int

in my case statement.

`[LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE]` and `[LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE]` are both `nvarchar` datatypes.

I have negative, positive, and null values in the table.
Can I set these fields to an `integer` before the SELECT statement?

```
CASE 
WHEN [LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE]>= 0 OR [LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE]>= 0 THEN 'YES'
WHEN [LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE] IS NULL OR [LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE] IS NULL THEN 'NO'
ELSE 'CHECK BUSINESS LOGIC'
END AS 'REVERSE POLARITY ISSUE',
```

Comment: -49.15 is not an integer value.

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think your value is float type or numeric type (-49.15 from nvarchar value). Then, you should convert nvarchar type to float type or numeric type. Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE NVARCHAR(10) = '-49.15'
DECLARE @LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE NVARCHAR(10) = '49.15'
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(FLOAT, @LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE) >= 0 -- OR NUMERIC
      OR CONVERT(FLOAT, @LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE) >= 0 THEN 'YES'
    WHEN @LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE IS NULL
      OR @LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE IS NULL THEN 'NO'
    ELSE 'CHECK BUSINESS LOGIC'
    END AS 'REVERSE POLARITY ISSUE'
```

Comment: the -49.15 is a variable...it ranges from -50.00 to +50.00 (i.e. -46.15 or +31.25)

Comment: I do not receive an error now but am not getting the desired result of yes or no...the negative results are stating yes when they should be no.

Comment: No luck because you can only use = in the declare variable

Comment: I would advise using `numeric(5,2)` over `float` - `float` could give you weird rounding issues that might be hard to debug, and should be avoided unless the data truly is floating point data.

Comment: i just pulled the distinct values of LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE and here are some of the values: 0  0.01  -0.01  0.73  -0.73  46.62  -46.62  anything with 0 or positive result should be flagged as YES and anything < 0 would be NO...seems simple enough but I am finding this table is full of garbage without any constraints...

Answer (score 0):

Just change the comparisons from integers to floating point numbers:

```
(CASE WHEN LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE >= 0.0 OR LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE >= 0.0
      THEN 'YES'
      WHEN LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE IS NULL OR LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE IS NULL
      THEN 'NO'
      ELSE 'CHECK BUSINESS LOGIC'
 END) AS [REVERSE POLARITY ISSUE],
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `try_convert()`:

```
(CASE WHEN try_convert(float, LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE) >= 0.0 OR 
           try_convert(float, LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE) >= 0.0
      THEN 'YES'
      WHEN LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE IS NULL OR LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE IS NULL
      THEN 'NO'
      ELSE 'CHECK BUSINESS LOGIC'
 END) AS [REVERSE POLARITY ISSUE],
```

Comment: THANKS but i am still receiving error:
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: In that case, the problem is invalid numeric values in the columns.

Comment: there are millions of records in the production environment, do you recommend a delete of these erroneous records?  i pulled the distinct values of this field and here some examples   null 0  0.01  -0.01 46.45 -46.45

Comment: i used the try_convert function without any luck

Answer (score 0):

Your data is going to have some serious issues at some point - storing integers in text-based fields produces all sorts of problems with converting on the fly. If you can't clean that up, we need to get a little tricky and make a heap of assumptions e.g. that any NULL will defeat any numeric value.

I'm going to assume you have an ID of some sort to query on, and I'll build a little table for a demo:

```
CREATE TABLE mynvarcharstuff (ID INTEGER, LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE nvarchar(50), LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO mynvarcharstuff VALUES (1, '-49.15', '-8.68'),  (2, '-49.15', NULL),    (3, '-18', '7.65'), (4, '26.5', '4')
,   (5, '49.15', NULL), (6, '25.3', '-12.4'),   (7, NULL, NULL),    (8, 'bob', '6.5'),  (9, ' 33', '')
```

Solving the issue of converting on the fly is done using a CTE (or temp table if you like) to sort it out as you go, based on those IDs:

```
WITH numeric_ids AS (
    SELECT  ID
    ,       CASE WHEN (LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE IS NULL OR LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CheckNull
    ,       CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CheckLine1
    ,       CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CheckLine2
    FROM    mynvarcharstuff
)
SELECT N.ID
, CASE
    -- If you move this line below either of the numeric checks, you potentially get errors - be careful!
    WHEN I.CheckNull = 1 THEN 'NO'  
    WHEN (I.CheckLine1 = 1 AND CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 2), [LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE]) >= 0.0) THEN 'YES'
    WHEN (I.CheckLine2 = 1 AND CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 2), [LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE]) >= 0.0) THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'CHECK BUSINESS LOGIC'
  END AS 'REVERSE POLARITY ISSUE'
FROM mynvarcharstuff N
JOIN numeric_ids I ON I.ID = N.ID
```

As we can't convert the columns on the fly, we need to first check they're able to be converted, then see if they're positive or NULL.

Note this isn't a perfect solution. If you have rules around whether NULL must exist in Line1 if it appears in Line2 and vice-versa, it works.

But you're better off cleaning the data with something like this:

```
DELETE
FROM    mynvarcharstuff
WHERE   (ISNUMERIC(LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE) = 0 AND LINE1_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE IS NOT NULL)
OR      (ISNUMERIC(LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE) = 0 AND LINE2_OPEN_LOOP_VOLTAGE IS NOT NULL)
```